# How can i see the location of Oracle Datafiles, query result set is returning a direct that starts with (+) e.g +DG_DATA/lv_vcpdata4

Tags: oracle, linux

I am trying to find the location of oracle data files in Linux and after querying the database, i find results where the data file path starts with a (+) as below:

+DG_DATA/lv_vcpdata4
+DG_DATA/lv_vcpdata5
+DG_DATA/lv_vcpdata6
+DG_DATA/lv_vcpdata7

But when i try to look into the linux OS i dont find any folder that starts with a (+), so where is this ++DG_DATA folder?

Answer (score 3):

They are stored in an ASM diskgroup, which is an Oracle specific concept, not visible with regular Linux commands.

[Introducing Oracle Automatic Storage Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/ostmg/asm-intro.html)